# How to transfer big data to mysql (JDBC) quickly?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, arraylist, prepared-statement

I have a code, which manage `ArrayList<priceItem>` and direct each item into MySQL using preparedStatement. I don't know how to boost speed of this code. I tried use `.addBatch()` but it didn't help. Here's code.

```
try {
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    preparetStmt = connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_NEW);
    for (int i = 0; i < priceItems.size(); i++) {
        preparetStmt.setString(1, priceItems.get(i).getName());
        preparetStmt.setString(2, priceItems.get(i).getQuantity());
        preparetStmt.setString(3, priceItems.get(i).getCost());
        preparetStmt.setString(4, priceItems.get(i).getAnnotation());
        preparetStmt.addBatch();
    }   
    preparetStmt.executeBatch();

    if (!connection.isClosed()) {
        System.out.print("DB is closed.");
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Help me to find way to increase speed of loading this statement. For 1500 items it's took above 2 min. I need to sent more than 150K items.

Comment: Do you have to use JDBC or do you have acces to the database server directly? If you have a file like csv it could be a lot faster do insert batches into the database

Comment: Check the docs for addBatch(). The way you are doing it looks wrong. There are batching tutorials on the web you can check out, too. Solving these kinds of problems will require backing up and starting from the known and working to the unknown. So it is going to be hard to get someone to help you with that.

Comment: Also, you should be clear if this is a one-time operation, or if this will be a typical regular sort of dataset movement. This has impacts on the schema, indexes, etc.

Comment: Now i m using JDBC and connect to the localhost, but in the future i d like to relocate db on the site.
I extract excel data with ApachePoi and translate it to the arraylist

Comment: MySQL can load CSV data directly. There is no need to involve JDBC or indeed Java in this at all. Why are you testing whether the connection is closed at a point where it cannot possibly be closed, and why are you printing that it's closed when it isn't?

Answer (score 1):

Lots of ways to improve this code:

1. Create smaller batches so you cut down on the network latency.
2. Use a transaction manager and commit batches.  Your rollback segment should not be as big as the total transaction.
3. Close your resources in a finally block.